# include a local custom font in bookdown

Tags: css, r, font-face, bookdown

In my project folder I have an assets folder that contains font files.

```
BCSans-Bold.woff
BCsans-Regular.woff
```

etc.

My _output.yml file points to my css

```
bookdown::gitbook:
   css: assets/style.css
```

and within this file I am using

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "BCSans";
  font-style: normal
  src:url('assets/BCSans-Regular.woff');
}
```

Which doesn't work and I get the error message in console

```
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource assets\assets/BCSans-Regular.woff
```

I'm more used to using shiny where everything in the `www` is automatically included. I'm not sure if there is something similar with bookdown or there is a yaml option I am missing.

Any advice on what the correct syntax or how to fix would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a wrong path. Font urls/paths need to be relative to the final css. If your fonts are in the assets folder just as the css - change the source property to  `src:url('BCSans-Regular.woff')`. BTW your css wouldn't work this way as you're missing a ";" after the font-style. You should also specify a font-weight (albeit the fallback would be "normal/400")